# Como armazenar um único caractere?

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Minha classe possui um atributo que é um único caractere. Posso armazenar como `string`, porém acho que o correto seria `char`. Só que este atributo pode receber um `int` (entre 0 e 9) de outro método. Como faço para salvar este número neste `char` sem erro?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 4):

Se você pode garantir que sempre virá entre 0 e 9 é basicamente matemática:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = 2;
        WriteLine(ToChar(x + 48));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dhwvfr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YFEC4g). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/IntToChar.cs).

O 48 é o código decimal da [tabela ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) para o caractere que representa 0. Se vier fora da faixa de 0 à 9 pode não dar o resultado esperado, embora em boa parte dos casos não terá problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o melhor jeito seria utilzar o tipo *string* e para facilitar encapsular o processo de conversão ou no construtor ou criar métodos para encapsular a a tribuição de valor:

```
using System;

namespace consoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var oneChar1 = new OneChar('a');
            Console.WriteLine(oneChar1.Property);

            var oneChar2 = new OneChar(1);
            Console.WriteLine(oneChar2.Property);
        }
    }

    public class OneChar
    {

        public OneChar(char c)
        {
            Property = Convert.ToString(c);
        }

        public OneChar(int i)
        {
            Property = Convert.ToString(i);
        }

        public string Property { get; private set; }

        public void SetProperty(char c)
        {
            Property = Convert.ToString(c);
        }

        public void SetProperty(int i)
        {
            Property = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: É mais prático usar um `internal set;` ao invés de declarar duas funções para alterar o valor duma propriedade.

Comment: A utilizção de duas fuções é para ilustrar o encapsulamento da regra de atribuição da propriedade.

Answer (score 0):

Uma string é um `char[]`, uma cadeia de caracteres. Fiz um método de extensão:

```
public static char ToChar(this string value) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new ArgumentException();

    // retorna o primeiro caractere da string
    // se não quiser usar o System.Linq, pode fazer "return value[0];"
    return value.First();
}
```

Esse método fará:

```
"a".ToChar();          // char 'a'
"1".ToChar();          // char '1'
"".ToChar();           // ArgumentException foi disparado
"321".ToChar();        // char '3'
"xyz".ToChar();        // char 'x'
```

Ele retorna sempre o primeiro caractere. Para usar com inteiros, veja:

```
1.ToString().ToChar();  // char '1'
```

Veja [**funcionando no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/QpUns7).